# Optimize: Divide an array into continuous subsequences of length no greater than k such that sum of maximum value of each subsequence is minimum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

*Optimize `O(n^2)` algorithm to `O(n log n)`.*

**Problem Statement**

Given array `A` of `n` positive integers. Divide the array into continuous subsequences of length no greater than `k` such that sum of maximum value of each subsequence is minimum. Here's an example.

If `n = 8` and `k = 5` and elements of the array are `1 4 1 3 4 7 2 2`, best solution is `1 | 4 1 3 4 7 | 2 2`. The sum would be `max{1} + max{4, 1, 3, 4, 7} + max{2, 2} = 1 + 7 + 2 = 10`.

**O(n^2) solution**

Let `dp[i]` be the minimum sum as in problem statement for subproblem array `A[0] ... A[i]`. `dp[0] = A[0]` and, for `0 < i < n` (`dp[-1] = 0`),

[image: dp[i] = min(0, i-k+1 <= j <= i)(dp[j - 1] + max{A[j], ..., A[i]})]

```
// A, n, k, - defined
// dp - all initialized to INF
dp[0] = A[0];
for (auto i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    auto max = -INF;
    for (auto j = i; j >= 0 && j >= i-k+1; j--) {
        if (A[j] > max)
            max = A[j];
        auto sum = max + (j > 0 ? dp[j-1] : 0);
        if (sum < dp[i])
            dp[i] = sum;
    }
}
// answer: dp[n-1]
```

**O(n log n) ?**

The problem author claimed that it was possible to solve this in `O(n log n)` time, and there are some people who were able to pass the test cases. How can this be optimized?

Comment: Your current algorithm has O(n*k) complexity, because the second loop does not look back more than `k` steps.

Comment: After finding the j that minimises dp[i], if it turns out that this j causes the final segment to have strictly fewer than k elements, then this j will also give a valid solution for dp[i+1].  Let m be the largest element in the final segment of the optimal solution for dp[i].  A[i+1] can either be > m or <= m; think about whether you can eliminate some tests in each case.

Comment: Wondering an example application of this question in real world, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**: I'm gonna change slightly your dynamic programming relation, so that there is no special case if `j = 0`. Now `dp[j]` is the answer for the first `j` terms`A[0], ..., A[j-1]` and:

`dp[i] = min(dp[j] + max(A[j], ..., A[i-1]), i-k <= j < i)`

The answer of the problem is now `dp[n]`.

---

Notice that if `j < i` and `dp[j] >= dp[i]`, you won't need `dp[j]` in the following transitions, because `max(A[j], ..., A[l]) >= max(A[i], ..., A[l])` (so it will be always better to cut at `i` instead of `j`.

Furthermore let `C[j] = max(A[j+1], ..., A[l])` (where `l` is our current index in the dynamic programming step, ie. `i` in your C++ program).

Then you can keep in memory some set of indices `x1 < ... < xm` (the "interesting" indices for the transitions of your dynamic programming relation) such that: `dp[x1] < ... < dp[xm]` (1).  Then automatically `C[x1] >= ... >= C[xm]` (2).

To store `{x1, ..., xm}`, we need some data structure that supports the following operations:

- Pop back (when we move from `i` to `i+1`, we must say that `i-k` is now unreachable) or front (cf. insertion).
- Push front `x` (when we have computed `dp[i]`, we insert it while preserving (1), by deleting the corresponding elements).
- Compute `min(dp[xj] + C[xj], 1 <= j <= m)`.

Thus some queue to store `x1, ..., xk` together with a `set` to store all `dp[xi] + C[xi]` will be enough.

---

How do we both preserve (1) and update `C` when we insert an element `i`?

- Before computing `dp[i]`, we update `C` with `A[i-1]`. For that we find the smallest element `xj` in the set `x` s.t. `C[xj] <= A[i-1]`. Then (1) and (2) imply `dp[j'] + C[j'] >= dp[j] + C[j]` for all `j' >= j`, so we update `C[xj]` to `A[i-1]` and we delete `x(j+1), ..., xm` from the set (*).
- When we insert `dp[i]`, we just delete all elements s.t. `dp[j] >= dp[i]` by popping front.
- When we remove `i-k`, it may be possible that some element destroyed in (*) is now becoming best. So if necessary we update `C` and insert the last element.

Complexity : `O(n log n)` (there could be at most `2n` insertions in the set).

This code sums up the main ideas:

```
template<class T> void relaxmax(T& r, T v) { r = max(r, v); }

vector<int> dp(n + 1);
vector<int> C(n + 1, -INF);
vector<int> q(n + 1);
vector<int> ne(n + 1, -INF);
int qback = 0, qfront = 0;
auto cmp = [&](const int& x, const int& y) {
    int vx = dp[x] + C[x], vy = dp[y] + C[y];
    return vx != vy ? vx < vy : x < y;
};
set<int, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);

dp[0] = 0;
s.insert(0);
q[qfront++] = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    C[i] = A[i - 1];
    auto it_last = lower_bound(q.begin() + qback, q.begin() + qfront, i, [=](const int& x, const int& y) {
        return C[x] > C[y];
    });

    for (auto it = it_last; it != q.begin() + qfront; ++it) {
        s.erase(*it);
        C[*it] = A[i - 1];
        ne[*it] = i;
        if (it == it_last) s.insert(*it);
    }

    dp[i] = dp[*s.begin()] + C[*s.begin()];

    while (qback < qfront && dp[q[qfront]] >= dp[i]) {
        s.erase(q[qfront]);
        qfront--;
    }

    q[qfront++] = i;
    C[i] = -INF;
    s.insert(i);

    if (q[qback] == i - k) {
        s.erase(i - k);

        if (qback + 1 != qfront && ne[q[qback]] > q[qback + 1]) {
            s.erase(q[qback + 1]);
            relaxmax(C[q[qback + 1]], C[i - k]);
            s.insert(q[qback + 1]);
        }

        qback++;
    }
}

// answer: dp[n]
```

This time I stress-tested it against your algorithm: [see here](http://ideone.com/pIrsmo).

Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Your code seems to return 14 on the example given in my question. I'm not sure if I understand what you do correctly, but this is how I do it: [Link](https://hastebin.com/tudalofaxa.cpp). Also, I start `A`, `dp` and `C` at index 1 and `C[j] = max{A[j], ..., A[i]}` in this code. I'm not sure how you handle property (2), so I'd love some clarifications for that. (`>= dp[i]` Test elimination here alone made my solution pass the test case, but for sakes of curiosity. Thanks!)

Comment: @AquaBlitz11: I updated my answer. Now it should work (note that you don't need `multiset` as all elements are distinct here).